# How to find the eigenvalues ​of the following block matrix $ \pmatrix{0&X\\ X^T&A} $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, block-matrices

Assume that  $X$ is an $1 \times n$ matrix. Also, $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. How to find the eigenvalues ​​of the following block matrix
$ \pmatrix{0&X\\ X^T&A} $?

Comment: Is there some prior knowledge that you have that you are trying to use? For example, do you know the eigendecomposition of $A$ in advance? If not, then you would find these eigenvalues in the same way that you find the eigenvalues of any other matrix.

Answer (score 4):

Call the matrix $Y$. If $Y$ has a zero eigenvalue, its determinant is zero. A nonzero eigenvalue $\lambda$ would satisfy

$$0=\text{det}(Y-\lambda I_{n+1})=\text{det}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-\lambda & X\\
X^{T} & A-\lambda I_{n}
\end{array}\right)=-\lambda\text{det}\left(A-\lambda I_n+\frac{1}{\lambda}X^{T}X\right)\\
\implies 0=\text{det}\left(\lambda A-\lambda^2 I_n+X^{T}X\right),$$

using the [block matrix determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) identity.

Comment: @OscarLanzi As I stated in my answer, the result holds when $\lambda\neq 0.$ It relies on invertibility of the top left block.

Comment: @OscarLanzi No, $X^T X$ is $n\times n$ since $X$ was specified by OP as a row vector. I've checked my answer many times by the way.

Comment: Missed that, thanks.